# No puedo llamar Clase

Tags: php, php7

No puedo llamar una clase por que la conexion se esta usando en otra, tengo una plantilla base header con la case de Usarios tengo esto:

```
<?php
//aca validamos la sesion para segun el tipo de rol en esta misma pagina abajo hacemos condicional segun rol mostrar un panel
require_once "../../Ingreso/modelo/modelousuarios.php";
$objetoUsuario  = new Usuario();
$verificaRol    = $objetoUsuario->getPerfil();
$ponerNombre    = $objetoUsuario->getNombres();
$ponerApellidos = $objetoUsuario->getApellidos();
$ponerEstado    = $objetoUsuario->getEstado();
```

en esa plantilla que es el header.php todo funciona muy bien, luego en otro archivo estoy llamando el header.php , e incluyo una nueva clase que es Administrador, pero no me ejecuta por que tengo una conexion activa en el header, este es el codigo del otro archivo:

```
require_once "../../plantillaAdmin/plantilla/header.php";
require_once "../Modelo/ModeloAdmin.php";

$objetoMostrarMunicipio = new Administrador();
$mostar                 = $objetoMostrarMunicipio->mostrarMunicipios();
```

se que esta activa en header, pero como hago para llamar las clases  en los otros archvos, por que como todas tienen el header, todos los archivos que llame una clase me va salir esto:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Conexion, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\SENA\conexion.php on line 2
```

Comment: No he entendido bien el problema, pero prueba a usar solo requiere o include en vez de require_once porque con el _once solo puedes llamarle una vez y creo que el problema va por ahí.

Comment: Debes tener solo una clase para conexión y, de preferencia, en un archivo aparte. Si ya lo tienes así, también inclúyela con `require_once` en cada script donde la usas.

Comment: No ya lo intente, no funciona, cada clase está heredando a la conexión..

Comment: El problema es que al tener una clase activa enun header.php, al  cual llamo en todas las vistas, ya que es la cabecera, y si en una vista llamo otra clase, que por ende razones tendra conexion, no me deja continuar, por que el header la tiene activa no se que hacer

Comment: Me gusta especular tanto como al que mas, pero con las 5 líneas de código que muestras es imposible hacernos siquiera una mínima idea de cual es el error, mucho menos la solución. Creo que deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Mi solucion fue la siguiente, en todas las clases que estaba incluyendo la conexion, les coloque require_once solo dentro de las clases que estuve heredando, y en los demas archivos hasta en la plantilla header, y en las demas vistas les deje include, y asi funciono, en conclusion la clase que nececiten las conexion, las llamamos con require_once

Comment: Amigo asumiendo estas usando php por objetos y solo como recomendacion, la conexion deberia ir en 1 solo lugar, dentro de una funcion en tu archivo de clases. De esta manera solo tus metodos llamaran a a la conexion cuando un objeto lo necesite. Si estas usando require_once en todos lados, estoy casi seguro que tu codigo no esta bien estructurado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas y aclaraciones, fueron de bastante ayuda

Comment: No está bien que todas las clases hereden la conexión, como dices en un comentario. Si es así, deberías revisar tu modelo de datos y estudiar más a fondo en qué consiste la herencia y cómo se usa.

Comment: gracias A. Cedano